# Deleting Time Date Stamp files with a.bat File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to delete timestamp files from our daylily back up. My previous script creates the time stamp like this:

```
  datetimef=%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%
```

The files come out like this 20150620_104243.

I have created a little bat file to delete the files inside the timestamp folder like this:

```
del /s /q /f E:\*.rar
```

I was wondering if I could change this to delete the timestamp file with some things like this:

```
del E:\%datetimef%
```

But this does not seem to be working for deleting the folder. Does anyone have any clues that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a folder in batch use `rmdir`

```
rmdir /s /q "E:\%datetimef%"
```

Which deletes folder and contents

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply I have tested this and the only problem I have is that it deletes all the other files in this directory is there anyway to just specify the date time stamp files only. Thanks.